# height svg by font size

Tags: html, css, svg

i have many text on site and some time i need add SVG icon in text in: p,h1,span,ul and other text based components.
How i can set SVG hight by text in this tags without **FLEX**?
i try line-height, height: 100%, dont help...

```
<h1>Hello <svg class="heightByFontSize"></svg> world!</h1>
<p>Hello <svg class="heightByFontSize"></svg> world!</p>
<span>Hello <svg class="heightByFontSize"></svg> world!</span>

.heightByFontSize{
    // ????
}
```

Comment: `height: 1em`, or similar ...?

Comment: 1:em on svg dont work https://i.ibb.co/bXsbSTJ/size.png

Comment: Don't post such screenshots on their own, those give us very little actually useful information. A [mre] is the proper way to present such problems here. Maybe it just needs _more_ than 1em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.heightByFontSize {
  height: 0.7em;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="heightByFontSize"><rect x="0" y="0" height="30" width="30" /></svg> world!</h1>
<p>Hello <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="heightByFontSize"><rect x="0" y="0" height="30" width="30" /></svg> world!</p>
<span>Hello <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="heightByFontSize"><rect x="0" y="0" height="30" width="30" /></svg> world!</span>
```

Comment: hi. If you zoom you will see that SVG out of text size https://i.ibb.co/TrnQJ98/size.png

Comment: Where should the top of the square be? Where should the bottom of the square be?

Comment: i need square be between RED lines

Comment: Sure. Just change the height.

Comment: yes it works, thank you. it looks strange, but there are no better solutions

Comment: Please see https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align